# WAV file splitter utility

Tags: wav, utility, filesplitting

I have a **PROGRAMMING** task (homework) to investigate brute force neural net methods. That part of the problem is **MY** homework.

We have to show that certain simple words repeated in a verbal conversion might be able to be recognized as similar. We don’t have to workout what the word is, just that it is a possible repeat. To limit my *‘search space’* I want to break up the WAV file into fragments. To avoid the *‘Donald Knuth’* syndrome I don’t want to divert energies into learning RMS, Fourier analysis for frequency profiling etc.

So I am looking for a windows based util to split wav files. I have looked at one called [GramoFile.exe](http://www.opensourcepartners.nl/~costar/gramofile/). It works well at the LP song level of breaking up vinyl platter recordings, but not at the small speech fragments. It is a Linux util with a DOS version. It is limited to split into **99** files only. I have tried to split to 99 fragments then run the first, second, etc split files through the GramoFile.exe but no luck. It can’t deal will the infinitesimal pauses between words.

Any suggestions people ?

Comment: That you have a programming task doesn't make the question programming related ;)

Comment: I know. But few sys admins over at serverfault spend their time splitting wave files and superuser is dead. So here is the best place to get an answer.

Comment: Technically, that you don't have any other, popular forum where you hope to get an answer doesn't make this question programming-related either.

Comment: Correct. I could of asked how to do the file splitting programaticaly to fit within the rules of this forum hopeing someone might say try this util as it does all you want. Would that of been a better strategy ?

Comment: I've also had questions which didn't really fit into any of the SO-family sites - thats just how it is. I also remember being able to solve problems before SO existed.

Comment: Looks like I will end up writing a util myself as nothing I have found will split down to the sub second that is required to seperate words. So perhaps I will re-submit my question as I has now become a progrmming task for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.nch.com.au/splitter/index.html

Answer (score 1):

A wav is pretty simple.

Here is a c# snippet I wrote earlier to read in a wav into two arrays (left, right channel). Once you have it there you can split it any way you like. It should not be hard to port to your language of choice.

[Mean amplitude of a .wav in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064168/mean-amplitude-of-a-wav-in-c/1064429#1064429)