# Changing Pitch/Amplitude of a WAVE File C#

Tags: c#, wav

What I am trying to do is read the Pitch/Amplitude of one wave file, then increase the pitch of another wave file depending on the Pitch/Amplitude of the first. The second part should be simple enough for me. But what library do I need to use (and what method). It would be great if anyone can help. At the moment I am using the SoundTouch http://code.google.com/p/soundtouchnet/ library to up the pitch.

Any help or tips is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Exactly what are you asking for help with?

Comment: I want to know how I can read the amplitude of a wave file at a given point

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064168/mean-amplitude-of-a-wav-in-c

Comment: Using the code found on the link above I can get the amplitudes ok. Is there a way to convert the modified amplitudes back to .wav

Comment: Using the code found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064168/mean-amplitude-of-a-wav-in-c helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using DirectSound.  This tool allows you to do whatever with wav files.  There are plenty of sources to find tutorials too.

Comment: The above link is probably the best as it allows me to edit it on byte level. And I will be wanting to use this on other OS's (e.g Android, iOS etc) so having knowledge of how to break down bytes is handy.