# Convert an array of 8-bit values to wav file in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, audio, wav, 8-bit

I have an array of 8-bit values which I have received from a microprocessor.
I am looking to turn those values into a wav file using PHP.

I found some examples, [like this](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145848/convert-amplitude-back-to-wav-file-c), that work in Java and C# but they all seem to leverage existing classes.
Does anyone know of a PHP library that can do this?
If not, can someone explain how to create a wav file in PHP?

Comment: All you need to do is write the RIFF headers.  I haven't seen a class in PHP to do this, but it should be pretty easy to do.  Wikipedia actually shows a bit of what should be in that header.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#RIFF_WAVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pack](http://php.net/pack) function, but first you must discover what values used: signed or unsigned

```
function pack_array($v,$a) {
 return call_user_func_array(pack,array_merge(array($v),(array)$a));
}

$wav = pack_array('c*', $array); // 'C*' for unsigned
```